# Duplicate method onCreate(Bundle) in type MainActivity?

Tags: java, android, oncreate

I do have two onCreate methods in MainActivity but when I rename it:

> The method onCreate1(Bundle) of type MainActivity must override or implement a supertype method

What I'm trying to do is to add a button that opens another activity to my app.

Now the error is gone but the button doesn't open the other activity.

Comment: Overrides android.app.Activity.onCreate.                                                    <This error also occurs when I don't rename it.

Comment: Remove the @Override on this method

Comment: ...and rename it to something other than onXYZ(). Only lifecycle or event listener methods should start with "on".

Comment: Ok, but when I change anything the error stays even when I do Project Clean and Project Build as well as refresh.

Answer (score 1):

The method you renamed to `onCreate1` shouldn't have the `@Override` annotation, since it doesn't override a method of the super class of your `MainActivity`.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `@Override` at line above, than your `onCreate1`. Because super class doesn't have `onCreate1()`, there's `onCreate()` method, not `onCreate1()`. Look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/basics.html
It's simple! Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

As an answer to what you are trying to accomplish, you should create another class that extends activity with it's own onCreate() and call that class from the original one using Intent().

Comment: Since I removed the @Override annotation, the method is useless. The button when pressed, does nothing.

Comment: Then don't use two onCreates in one class. Put the original back and and the @Override again. Then put the other onCreate in it's own class and call it with Intent when you press the button.

Comment: It has its own class that contains its own activity and layout but it is opened from main activity by button pressed. Should I put the button in a separate class?

Comment: To be able to help you with this, I think you should show your code to us.

Comment: I would have to create a repository because I can't show you which part specifically contains the error.

Comment: You could start by showing the (main) class extending Activity that has the buttonpress in it. Or, save it as a picture and put a link to it in your comment.